# A problem on the set of all points of differentiability of a real and real-valued function

Tags: analysis, derivatives

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Does there exist a function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f$ is continuous on the whole real line but differentiable at precisely countably infinitely many points ?

$\mathbf {My \ approach} :$ Actually, we almost all know about the Weierstrass function $\operatorname {W(x)}$ such that $\operatorname W$ is continuous on the whole real line but nowhere differentiable.

Then the function $\operatorname {W_n(x)} = (x-x_1)^2(x-x_2)^2\cdots(x-x_n)^2\operatorname {W(x)}$
is continuous on whole of $\mathbb R$ but differentiable at only the distinct points $x_1,x_2,\cdots x_n$, but I can't think about the "countably infinitely" case.

Again, the set of all points of continuity $\operatorname C_f$, of a function $f :\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a $G_\delta$ set, but is there any speciality 
about the set of all points of differentiability $\operatorname D_f$ of $f ?$

I think an answer to the above question can throw some light on the answer of the posted question.

Comment: Take an infinite version of the product you have, $\sin(x)W(x)$. The square is unnecessary since it serves to make the derivative zero.

Comment: @NinadMunshi, Sir, can you explain your answer a little bit ? How can you show that an infinite version of the product is continuous on the whole real line and differentiable at only countably infinitely many points ?

Comment: @NinadMunshi, Sir, can you please provide me a hint about the 2nd problem on the set of all points of differentiability of $f$ ?